# How to extract osm poi categories

Tags: openstreetmap

This is an example of osm xml:

```
  <node id="1000" ...>
...
    <tag k="shop" v="supermarket"/>
  </node>

  <node id="26999673" ...>
...
    <tag k="public_transport" v="station"/>
    <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
    <tag k="train" v="yes"/>
  </node>
```

I know that "shop", "railway", "station"  are poi categories, because I am human. But how can I extract them by script?

Comment: If you are looking just for retrieving certain categories from OSM, see the overpass-api (http://overpass-turbo.eu/ & http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)

Comment: I want to exctract list of categories. How does overpass-api help?

Comment: Overpass only helps if you want to extract specific tags, or just everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: https://github.com/kiselev-dv/gazetteer it will generate JSON with addresses, and pois also with address. Pois are categorized according to https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc so you can define your own POI types.

Comment: Thank you. Your category list is not full.  https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/blob/master/catalog/hierarchies/osm-me.xml,  <group name="shops">
<title>Экстренные службы</title>
</group>.  This translation is wrong.

Comment: There three kinds of objects.

Main type is feature, they are [here](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/tree/master/catalog/features) They allows you to parse poi from osm & write tham back.

Next type hierarchies. They allows you to arrange features by categories. They are [here](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/tree/master/catalog/hierarchies) osm-me.xml is just a draft.

Comment: And third: traits, they are [here](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/tree/master/catalog/traits) it's something like additional tags presets.

Comment: Do you have [this](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/tree/master/catalog/features) list in one file (better JSON)?

Comment: I have java api for such purposes. This data based on another project, with slightly different data structure. https://github.com/ErshKUS/osmCatalog/ and there you can get it as JSON.

Comment: I also have this data as one xml file. https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/osm-doc.xml but it's still rather hard to understand how it should work. Hope [xsd](https://github.com/kiselev-dv/osm-doc/blob/master/schema/osm-doc-part.xsd) with comments may help you. Or you can connect me via github.

Comment: Here it is, excellent: https://github.com/ErshKUS/osmCatalog/blob/master/catalog.json

Answer (score 1):

That entirely depends on your interpretation of *POI* which is a very broad term.

Mappers in OSM are allowed to use [any tags they like](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Any_tags_you_like). Consequently there is no such thing as a POI *category*. But there are many frequently used [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) of which most are documented at the [map features wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features).

Comment: Ok. Tags or categories, nodes or POIs, doesn't matter. How can I guess that "k" is a tag? "K" can be "name", "website" and many other not tags.

Comment: These are all tags. A *tag* is defined by a *key* and a *value*, hence names and websites are tags, too. It seems to me you are mixing things up a little. What is the purpose of your application? Most applications will only handle a limited, fixed set of tags anyway. Do you really want you application to handle unknown tags? Maybe this isn't necessary at all.